# how to call url in ajax json request

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, json

i need to call webservice from a directory in my project but

> url: "~/RA/WebServiceRAOpen.asmx/OpenedRAlistByBranch" but it is not working

```
$.ajax({
     url: "~/RA/WebServiceRAOpen.asmx/OpenedRAlistByBranch",
                            data: "{ 'ranumber': '" + request.term + "' }",
                            dataType: "json",
                            type: "POST",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    })
```

hiow can i call the url from a directory

Comment: when am debugging my url coming with some port number how can i know which port number it is http://localhost:2546/VehicleReplacement

Comment: try using full url `"http://MyWebService/RA/WebServiceRAOpen.asmx/OpenedRAlistByBranch"`

Comment: i think your  url is invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try building up the url with the abolute server path, e.g. using [window.location](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp) like this:

```
$.ajax({
   url: window.location.host + "/RA/WebServiceRAOpen.asmx/OpenedRAlistByBranch"
...
```

A relastive url should also work. Just leave out the "~"-prefix. Note that you should execute JavaScript code not locally but from a real http server. Debugging in Visual Studio uses a local http server, so this will do.

Answer (score 0):

Urls starting with `~/` are ASP.NET Urls. To use it in JavaScript you need to map it to actual Urls. Render the path on your page into a JavaScript variable and then use it in your script.

`HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/RA/WebServiceRAOpen.asmx/OpenedRAlistByBranch")` will get you the actual path. I have not used ASP.NET in a while, so I do not remember the correct asp:label syntax anymore to get you the full way.